# Append dynamically created checkbox to each row not working

Tags: jquery, codeigniter-2

I've this to append dynamically created checkbox in each row of table. I don't know why this is not working.

```
<script>
    $(".ajaxcall").click(function () {
//        $("#subcattablerows").remove();
        $("#subcattable tbody").empty();
        var cat_id = $(this).data("catid");
//        alert(cat_id);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "<?php echo base_url() . 'Products/getsubcat' ?>",
            data: {"cat_id": cat_id},
            success: function (result) {
//                console.log(result.result);
//                $('#result').html(Result);
                var JSONObject = result.result;
                for (var key in JSONObject) {
                    if (JSONObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                        $('#subcattable').append(
                                "<tr style='width: 100%; display: inline-table;'>"
                                + "<td>"+"<input type='checkbox'>" + JSONObject[key]["subcatname"] + "</td>"
                                + "</tr>"
                                );
                        console.log(JSONObject[key]["subcatname"]);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you setup jsfiddle? It seems you want to append new <td> to each existing <tr> in the table but somehow you append to whole <table>?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cxvnp12h/

Comment: There are two tables left and right. When i click on <td> of left table, data loaded in right table with checkboxe with each entry.

Comment: I do recommend to review e.g.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171027/add-table-row-in-jquery or https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=faq&file=jquery-append-and-remove-table-row-dynamically. both should give you enough ideas on what is wrong.

Comment: Thanks @mybrave i got the issue